# ARCore integrate depth sensors for AR applications using the front-facing camera?

Tags: android, ios, arcore

I can't seem to find this anywhere.

When running apps that rely on the front camera, does ARCore inherently make use of the depth sensor, if available in the phone?

Is Google actively working to potentiate front camera usage? Does ARCore integrate depth sensors for AR applications using the front-facing camera?

Comment: Plese be specific about your question else this question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Google ARCore does not make use of the depth sensors:

https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/206